# How to setup Proxy in a Python script

Tags: python, python-requests

I have tried using `requests.post`

```
def creat(script,reason):

    split=script.split('.')
    json_file=LOG_DIR+split[0]+".json"

    url='my url'
    p1={'proxy1','proxy2'}
    createJSON(script,json_file,reason)
    fp=open(json_file,'rb').read()
    print "\nJSON File :"
    print fp
    b=requests.post(url,proxies=p1,data=fp,headers=headers,auth=auth)
    # s = requests.session()
    #s.proxies.update(p1)
    #s.post(p1)
    content=b.json()
```

The script executes but it looks like the Proxies are not getting applied. The error is

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The `proxies` argument expects a `dict`, not a `set`.

The `dict` should be a mapping of protocol to host, or protocol-and-host to host, as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.proxies)

> `proxies = None`
>
> Dictionary mapping protocol or protocol and host to the URL of the proxy (e.g. >      `{'http': 'foo.bar:3128', 'http://host.name': 'foo.bar:4012'}`) to be used on each `Request`.

If you're trying to specify a proxy for HTTPS connections, then it should look like this:

```
import requests

# ... your stuff ...

# Without knowing what either of your proxies are meant for,
# I'm going to just specify one proxy here for ALL https connections
proxies = { 'https': 'proxy1' }

# ... more of your stuff ...
b = requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, data=fp, headers=headers, auth=auth)

# ... more and more of your stuff ...
```